# DAX Difficulty counting rows and assigning a rank

Tags: dax, rank, summarize

I'm trying to select lines from table Cases, count the rows for each Broker in the list, and then get the rank for each Broker.  My code works up to the last step.  I know that because the measure that used the code up to Table 2 is giving me correct results.  But I'm doing something wrong in calculating the rank.  Can you tell me what the problem is?  I tried using ALL(Table3), but that gave me a syntax error ("All needs a table reference, not a table expression.")

This is driving me nuts. I've wasted hours trying variations, looking for examples, reading documentation, but there's something here I just don't get.  I finally got the FILTER, SELECTCOLUMNS, SUMMARIZE, and ADDCOLUMNS sequence working correctly.  (Although using SUMMARIZE to add a column is apparently not recommended--but it seems to work OK here.)

```
BrkPricedCtRank = 
VAR Table0 = 
FILTER ( 'Cases',
    not ISBLANK( [Date To Pricing] )
    && [Date Initiated] >= date(2021,1,1)
    && [Date Initiated] <= DATE(2021,12,31)  )

VAR Table1 =
SELECTCOLUMNS( 
    Table0,  
    "Broker", [Broker]
    )

VAR Table2 = 
SUMMARIZE(
    Table1,
    [Broker], 
    "PricedCt", COUNTROWS( Table1 )  )

--For measure BrkPricedCt. the code continues with these 2 lines.
--That measure gives me what I want.
--   RETURN
--      MINX( Table2, [PricedCt] )

VAR Table3 = 
     ADDCOLUMNS( 
         Table2,
         "Rank", RANKX( Table2, [PricedCt] )  )

return MINX( Table3, [Rank] )
```

Here is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using RANKX on Table2 and then adding it in a visual you add a filter to each row which will evaluate to 1 on all rows (all are ranked number 1 in their own row = context). But we want to have ranking for all rows which we achieve by changing to RANKX( ALL(Table2), [PricedCt] ) or RANKX( ALLSELECTED(Table2), [PricedCt] ) if you still want the ranking to be 1, 2, 3 when filtering only certain brokers.

Comment: Yes, I thought of something like that, but it doesn't work. RANKX( ALL(Table2), [PricedCt] ) gives me a syntax error, as I mentioned in my question:  
The ALL function expects a table reference for argument '1', but a table expression was used. 

Thanks for explaining why it gives me rank 1 on each row. That's helpful.

The process of adding or selecting columns is something I can never seem to get to work.
```

Comment: Ok, sorry that didn't help. In general this should work like "RANKX( ALL('Dim Kunder'), [Utfall kkr])" but I guess there's something else. Have you tried to return only the rank part? Can you try separating Table2 as an own table (create table) and then use rank in another measure so you see what's going on? Or possibly use DAX Studio to easier debug. Do you have any sample data?

Comment: I've been using DAX Studio, but that's only helped a little.  It tells me I've built the table correctly.    I've tried returning only the rank part. When I use RETURN RANKX( Table2, [PricedCt]) I get an error, "The value for "PricedCt" cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column."  I'll look into making Table2 its own table when I get some time.

Comment: A calculated table works, sort of, but without the functionality I need. The problem is that I don't want to hard-code the dates, as in the original code example.  I want to use harvest measures from the Calendar date table, [MinDate] and [MaxDate].  (I didn't set up a relationship between the tables and the Calendar, because I have 5 different dates I need to filter on, and I'd go nuts with multiple UseRelationship functions or multiple Calendar tables.)

Since a calculated table is static, you can't dynamically change its content with filters.  (If you can, someone please tell me how.)